# See what API a webpage calls

Tags: api, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools

Say I have a webpage that renders all it's contect using javaScript.

It has to fetch the data from somewhere (likely some API). How do I see what webpages/API the javaScript calls?

I have used the chrome-console and looked under fetch/XHR, but the only thing that pops up is an .svg file.

Do I need then to inspect each javaScript function under `JS` and look at, what they call or..?

Answer (score 0):

Finding out which servers are contacted via Devtools is not always easy. You can try extensions like webQsee (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webqsee-web-sniffer-recor/gamdpfnfkjknkimfbboonmgdfnondfme). They explicitely list the domains the browser is communicating with.

[image]